# @Scheduled not working with Web Sockets & Destination Variable

Tags: java, websocket

When a user goes to a specific end-point to find a stock-price, I want the stock price to update on the page every 3 seconds.

@Scheduled is not working on the following code:

```
    @MessageMapping("/stocks/{name}")
    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 3000)
public void stockData(@DestinationVariable String name) throws Exception {
    Stock stock = YahooFinance.get(name);
    simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic/stocks/" + name, stock);
}
```

JS front-end code:

```
var stompClient = null;
function connect(url) {
    console.log("connect() called")
    var socket = new SockJS('/stocks');
    
    stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
    
    stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) {
        console.log("connected")

        setConnected(true);

        stompClient.subscribe('/topic/stocks/' + url, function(
                retrieveSingleStockData) {
            console.log('retrieving...');
            display(retrieveSingleStockData.body);
        });
    }, function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```

The stomp-client can subscribe without any issues, but the method in the controller isn't sending back any data. I know it's an issue with the @Scheduled annotation.

I'd appreciate any help, thanks